How to use Gradio Client to generate images
I'm using gradio_client (Python) to generate images using the API, and the official space has a GPU issue, so I used https://dudeicuf-black-forest-labs-flux-1-schnell.hf.space (the problem also happens with Stable Diffusion), the result SHOULD be a vaild link to the file, right? It's the path of the file on the server, so I requested https://dudeicuf-black-forest-labs-flux-1-schnell.hf.space/file=<myfilepath>, to see a JSON-formatted 404 message. This happens only with the API.
